# QTreeview children indicators repaint

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtreeview

Good day, I have QTreeView and some background threads, not GUI threads add in model items, the problem is when displaying my view children-indicator not repaint but they exists (if you press to the place where they placed the node expanded), I emit signal `dataChange`, but my children-indicator not repaint.

What am I doing wrong?
This is code in background thread which I call:

```
void notify()
    {
        if (file_item_type::parent())
        {
            file_item_type::parent()->notify(this);
        }
        file_item_type::filesystem_type::s_notify.dataChange(this);
    }
```

then in model

```
void FileItemModel::dataChangeItem(void *it)
{
    file_item_type *item = static_cast<file_item_type*>(it);
    if(item&&isWatchedDir(item))
    {
        int row = indexOfChild(item);
        if (row>=0)
        {
            QModelIndex indexT = createIndex(row, eDC_Name, item);
            QModelIndex indexL = createIndex(row, eDC_Size, item);
            emit dataChanged(indexT,indexL);
        }
    }
}
```

and after that I catch my `dataChanged` signal in proxy model

```
void FileProxyTreeModel::sourceDataChanged( const QModelIndex& from, 
                                            const QModelIndex& to )
{
    emit dataChanged( mapFromSource( from ), mapFromSource( to ) );
}
```